ng appName --createApplication=false
when I try to create folder/package in angular version 18. with the below command
ng new appName --createApplication=false

I am getting error like:
Error: Unknown argument: createApplication

is that only with angular version 18X?

I think you need to use pass the argument like below
ng new docs

If you plan to have multiple applications in the workspace, you can create an empty workspace by using the --no-create-application option. You can then use ng generate application to create an initial application. This allows a workspace name different from the initial app name, and ensures that all applications reside in the /projects subfolder, matching the structure of the configuration file.

ng new appName --no-create-application

